# What is $Recycle.Bin in LS output?

Tags: directory, filename

If i do LS and see

```
$RECYCLE.BIN
```

and try to TAB complete $R

I get

```
$RANDOM
```

clearly I am an idiot, but breaking things is how I learn :)

I deleted $RECYCLE.BIN and lost a bunch of files.

Now testdisk is recovering into

```
$RJNUMBERSANDLETTERS folders
```

I can't CD into them to test if the file integrity which I want to do before letting it finish recovering for 20 plus hours.

Is this because the folder was originally deleted on the HD and is stored in $RHASD etc etc?

I don't expect all files to be in $RASD format, I think it is recovering files from previos deletion. IE: These files were all ready gone when I deleted $RECYCLE.BIN.

But also for prosterities sake of the internet

**What does $FOLDER represent?**

Note: I think this might be ntfs related? My ExtHD's are NTFS my Interal HD's are Ext4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` when passing it to the `ls` command in the terminal, as `$` is a special character used for referencing environment variables in the shell.

Running `ls \$RECYCLE.BIN` will list the contents of that folder, or only that file, depending on which it is. As for the `$RECYCLE.BIN` directory itself, it is a special directory on NTFS partitions, if you move files to *Recycle Bin* in Windows, they end up in that directory on the partition, until you empty the *Recycle Bin*.

Comment: Can't believe that slipped past me.... but why is test disk recovering into folders starting with $ is that because they were inside recycle bin perhaps?

Comment: I can confrim that the other files are being exported in regular folders now, thanks, I am going to change the title to $Recycle.bin for others to find as its mostly an NTFS thing... Its amazing the power of sudo lol, got another 15 hours of data recovery for one sudo line